# why `rxjs/no-async-subscribe` exists? What's wrong with `async` inside `subscribe`

Tags: typescript, rxjs, eslint

There is a rule from eslint-rxjs that is [`rxjs/no-async-subscribe`](https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-rxjs/blob/main/docs/rules/no-async-subscribe.md)

The forbidden pattern is (the `async` keyword is forbidden):

```js
of(42).subscribe(async () => console.log(value));
```

Why is that a bad thing?

I've seen somewhere that it's because it's not supported but I've tested it and it works, I can use `await` inside the callback function and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule is trying to force/encourage the developer to use rxjs's operators (eg, the various map functions), rather than async functions. By doing so, features of observables like cancellation and retrying will work, whereas they would not with an async function.

This rule originally came from rxjs-tslint-rules, and then was added to eslint to match. The original justification, as described in [this pull request](https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-tslint-rules/issues/84), was (emphasis added):

> A mistake I often see people less familiar with Rx make is doing async things in subscribe():
>
> ```
> events.subscribe(async value => {
>   const data = await fetchData(url, value)
>   const moreData = await fetchMoreData(url2, data)
>   displayData(moreData)
> })
> ```
>
> **This is bad because it does not handle cancellation of the operations and is
> therefor prone to race conditions**.
> Instead, it should be this:
>
> ```
> events.pipe(
>  switchMap(value => fetchData(url, value)),
>  switchMap(value => fetchMoreData(url2, data)),
> ).subscribe(displayData)
> ```
>
> This can be done by enforcing that the subscribe() observer functions return void

Comment: Thanks for this, but I'm not sure to understand what doesn't work, what is cancellation or retrying ?

Comment: By cancelling i mean unsubscribing. That happens when you explicitly call unsubscribe, but it also happens automatically behind the scenes with operators like `takeUntil` or `switchMap`.  By retrying, i mean things like the `retry` or `repeat`, which will subscribe again when certain conditions are met. These operators cannot stop an async function that's already running, nor start one in the middle, but they can do that if you use rxjs for everything, and just subscribe to the very last step.